Searching for sequential values in multiple columns
I'm trying to extract a list of products that are in sequential locations. My problem is that the sequential values are spread across multiple columns.
The locations would be A001 to A122.
Could anyone please give me a steer on how to achieve the table highlighted green?
Thanks for your help.
Paul


Input:



Product
Loc1
Qty1
Loc2
Qty2
Loc3
Qty3




FALLONES16
A001
19






FALLONES12
A002
36






POL02
A009B
42
A020B
42
A035
42


OIPLTMBS
A014b
84
a053b
84
A004
17


PIZ9-C
A016B
42
A003
23
a081b
42


PRPIZ9
A021
47
A063A
42
A075A
42


10012181
A023A
42
A034A
42
A114b
42


JDMFCH
A024B
80
A107A
42
A004
34


MFCH
A005
112
F045
44







What should be the logic behind Loc3 A004 since there are two of them?

Good point...I've amended the results list to reflect the dual location. The second location and product would also get added to the list. A location could have more than one product.

If you are on MS365, you do it like this:
I put your data in A1:G10,



Product
Loc1
Qtyl
Loc2
Qty2
Loc3
Qty3




FALLONES16
A001
19






FALLONES12
A002
36






POL02
A009B
42
A020B
42
A035
42


OIPLTMBS
A014b
84
a053b
84
A004
17


PIZ9-C
A016B
42
A003
23
a081b
42


FRplZ9
A021
47
A063A
42
A075A
42


10012181
A023A
42
A034A
42
A114b
42


JDMFCH
A024B
80
A107A
42
A004
34


MFCH
A005
112
F045
44





You can use below to list (Loc, Qty) pairs for product MFCH
=LET(
    product, A10,
    locs, B10:G10,
    wrapped_locs, WRAPROWS(TOROW(locs, 1, FALSE), 2, ""),
    HSTACK(EXPAND(product, ROWS(wrapped_locs), 1, product), wrapped_locs)
)

The result looks like this:

Then you need to do the same thing for each product, and stack the results into one big table and then sort the table by "Loc".
You may use REDUCE to stack the (Loc, Qty) pair for each product, here is the formula you can use:
=LET(
    product_list, A2:A10,
    all_loc_data, B2:G10,
    header, HSTACK("Product", "Loc", "Qty"),
    loc_data_by_product_with_header, REDUCE(
        header,
        SEQUENCE(ROWS(product_list), 1, 1, 1),
        LAMBDA(list, row_idx,
            LET(
                product, INDEX(product_list, row_idx, ),
                locs, INDEX(all_loc_data, row_idx, ),
                wrapped_locs, WRAPROWS(TOROW(locs, 1, FALSE), 2, ""),
                product_loc_data, HSTACK(EXPAND(product, ROWS(wrapped_locs), 1, product), wrapped_locs),
                VSTACK(list, product_loc_data)
            )
        )
    ),
    loc_data_by_product, DROP(loc_data_by_product_with_header, 1, ),
    sorted_loc_data_by_product, SORT(loc_data_by_product, 2, 1, FALSE),
    VSTACK(header, sorted_loc_data_by_product)
)

The resulting table is like this:


If I have understood correctly, from the post requirements then the following formula should work and it also assumes as per the tags listed, there is no Excel Constraints.

Extract Products that are in sequential locations.
Locations would be from A001 to A122 respectively.




• Formula used in cell I1
=LET(
     _Data, A1:G10,
     _Pro, DROP(TAKE(_Data,,1),1),
     _LocQty, DROP(_Data,1,1),
     _Header, LEFT(DROP(TAKE(_Data,1),,1),3),
     _Repivot, HSTACK(
               TOCOL(IF((_Header="Loc")*(_LocQty<>""),_Pro,0/0),2),
               WRAPROWS(TOCOL(_LocQty,1),2)),
     _Pos, XMATCH(INDEX(_Repivot,,2),"A"&BASE(SEQUENCE(122),10,3)),
     _Output, SORT(HSTACK(FILTER(_Repivot,1-ISNA(_Pos)),TOCOL(_Pos,2)),4),
     VSTACK(HSTACK("Product",UNIQUE(_Header,1)),
     DROP(FILTER(_Output, 1-ISNA(XMATCH(TAKE(_Output,,-1),SEQUENCE(ROWS(_Output))))),,-1)))



Brief explanation starting with the LET() function to use defined variables to reduce the use of redundant calculations/ranges etc, while increasing the performance as well.
_Data variable defines the whole data range.
_Pro variable defines the Product Range extracted using DROP() and TAKE().
LocQty variable defines the Location and Qty Ranges, extracted using DROP() function.
_Header variable defines the header the source, extracted for applying following conditions as well using it as header in the output, uses a mixture of DROP(), TAKE() and LEFT().
_Repivot variable defines, the reformatting of the data in tabular layout. Uses, HSTACK() , TOCOL(), IF() logic based on which the Product range is returned as single dynamic array, and use of WRAPROW() for the _LocQty converting it into a 2-Dimensional Array
Based on second condition of the post, returning locations within the ask range, using XMATCH() and BASE()+SEQUENCE(), defined as _Pos.
Returning a sorted _Output using SORT() function based on the above [include] within FILTER() function as, well combining the _Pos without any error, this is added for the 1st Conditions in the OP.
The above fulfils the 2nd Conditions in the OP. Now final retouch to ensure it the locations are sequential, hence getting those by finding the positions of each using XMATCH() and SEQUENCE() function, returns either a number or an error, parsing the errors to make TRUE and FALSE using 1-ISNA() (same as ISNUMBER() but this is shorter), which acts as the **[include] part of the FILTER() function, finally DROP() last column to get the actual output needed.
In the ultimate output a header is added, one can use or keep based on one's preference. Done.


NOTE: Formula works with MS365 Exclusively. This doesn't require a LAMBDA() iterations. 


Both given answer might be correct, but they are extremely complicated. Maybe you might be helped by this simple formula to start with:
=MATCH(B10;UNIQUE(B$10:B$17);0)

The results can be seen in this screenshot: (cell "C1" contains the Unique() result)


The formulas look complicated but the logic is quite simple. But I agree that adding some helper columns and doing it step by step is the more Excel-ish thing to do.

@rachel: in fact, the helper column is not even needed, it's just there for explanatory purposes :-)
